# std::thread in C++11, how to ensure a thread is finished inside a destructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I want to make sure a thread is completed before an object is destructed.

Here is the most basic example I could think of:

```
struct User {
    std::thread worker_thread;

    ~User() {
        if (worker_thread.joinable()) {
            worker_thread.join();
        }
    }
};
```

Is this a correct approach to the problem?

Comment: I see it ok, but you must ensure that the thread will finish eventually. If it is a server thread with an endless loop you should signal it first.

Comment: You need to properly quit the thread...

Comment: `std::thread` is a low level primitive.  Something like the above is a decent last-ditch way to avoid undefined behavior, but if you want to be using raw `std::thread`s, you shouldn't be: you should be wrapping them up in a lot more layers than something that thin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not correct, as `join()` may throw an exception, and you don't want to let any exception escape any destructor. From Herb Sutters [Exceptional C++](http://aalmos.kaniserver.net/doc/cpp/Exceptional%20C%2B%2B.pdf) in the section *Destructors That Throw and Why They're Evil.*:

> Observe the canonical exception safety rules: Never allow an exception to escape from a destructor or from an overloaded operator `delete()` or `operator delete[]();` write every destructor and deallocation function as though it had an exception specification of "`throw()`
>   ."

Comment: Um, that's why the code checks whether the thread is joinable. Of course, there is also the possibility that the code is attempting to join the current thread, but that would be the result of a serious design error, and shouldn't produce exception paranoia. But if you're **really** worried that there will be an exception, wrap the call in a try block.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with Pete in here.

Comment: From the [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join) `std::thread::join()` is allowed to throw `std::system_error` if `joinable() == false` or an _error occurs_.

One of the main benifits of exceptions is that they help root out programming errors. So calling `join()` in a destructor absolutely requires a try-catch block (thanks to Pete Becker for pointing this out), but the particular catch block is then responsible for reporting the programming error in whatever manor is relevant on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

I also think it is fine as mentioned in the comment, but you need to make sure to properly quit a thread if needed.

For instance, if you have a loop counter counting down slowly, you would need to properly close before the long waiting queue. Even more to that when you have an "endless" boolean condition for instance that has to be toggled, et cetera.

Comment: A worker_thread might be finishing writing a file, so I want to make sure the file finishes before the thread destructs.

Comment: Yeah, that is fine then, I would say, although you might wanna update your question with that. ;-)